# Rating Formula Design (conceptual not coding)

Tags: php, sql, math, rating, logarithm

One element of my site is a  rating system.  I am puzzled a bit by how best to set up the formula and I hope someone with more math aptitude can help me.

Users upload pictures that are rated 1-10 by other users.  The users rating then is the average of those scores.

Simple enough.  However, I want to add some system which rewards users for uploading more pictures.  SO that the formula would be average of ratings + some function of the number of pictures uploaded.

An example might be, Rating = AVG + .05 * Count

This formula would be somewhat fair for users who have uploaded 1-20 pictures... However, if users upload 2000 pictures they will have bipassed the entire rating system and automatically will have a 10/10.

So, my limited knowledge of post algebra math is failing. What would be some formula that would produce the desired effect?  The word "log" keeps bouncing around in my head--but I honesty can't remember anything about why... :)

Comment: I believe [this is the traditional blog post](http://evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html) to link to in this situation.

Comment: cool post but i don't think it solves the problem

Comment: @epsilon'εⳆ2'halbe, I wasn't suggesting it solved the problem; though I think it could easily be extended to do so. I was commenting on the statement: "The users rating then is the average of those scores."

Comment: I will definitely remember to see this blogpost if i should ever do a user rating-procedure!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do something like:

```
Rating = Average + (\sum_{i=1}^numofuploads 1/i)*scalefactor
```

though the sum grows to infinity - the sum grows very slowly

### Edit:

The idea is basically the same as with @maxhud's solution you add less points to your rating for every picture, and for simplicity say scaling is 1/3, and for now i use exact not floating point math

```
1 -> avg + (1/1)*.3 = avg + 1/3
2 -> avg + (1/1+1/2)/3 = avg + (3/2)/3) = avg + 1/2
3 -> avg + (3/2+1/3)/3 = avg + (10/6)/3 = avg + 10/18 = avg + 5/9 ~ avg + .55555
4 -> ...
```

technically the series (1+1/2+1/3+…) is going to infinity but you'd have to upload a huge amount of pictures to go over 50 - so you'd better choose your scaling factor carefully and give a bit, of thought. If you want to have a maximum of points that can be achieved via uploading this is the *WRONG* solution. You should rather go with something like

```
avg + scaling*(.9^n)
```

where `n` is the number of pictures. if you could upload infinitely many pictures you would have

```
avg + scaling*(1/(1-.9)) = avg + 10*scaling
```

for your rating: which is, as I commented, much better.

ps: I think @maxhud should leave

```
avg + numofpics*scale*(.9^numofpics)
      ^^^^^^^^^
```

because after uploading 10 pictures you have outweight your shrinking growth function.

Comment: This is the same concept as my answer.

Comment: it is not quite - there is an unnecessary loop in it - (though it is short) and your solution is not as easily understandable - as yours.

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more.

Answer (score 4):

Just do something like:

avg + numofpics*scale*(.9^numofpics)

This will make it do that as they upload more pictures they get less and less. You can change .09 (the rate of decay) depending on how many pictures you expect the average user to upload.

This the equation used for half life decay

Comment: +1 i like it more than my approach - it's much more adjustable

Comment: You probably shouldn't do it by 20s as that's a pretty high benchmark. Maybe by 5s. Whatever you choose you would divide the number of pictures by that in my equation.

Answer (score 3):

Consider an alternative approach - you want to reward users by increasing for uploading images but perhaps the user is uploading many many images that are not rated highly. Do you want to reward them if the majority of their images are poor?? Consider stackoverflow as an example - you can answer many many questions, but if they are not considered "good" by the rest of the community your reputation will not increase, no matter how many answers you provide.

It is possible that this is not how you want to do it and want to reward quantity rather than quality, but should you decide the opposite you could try something like

```
    UserRating = 10 * (AverageRating/10 + Scalefactor*((AverageRating/10)^2 * ImageUploadCount)))
```

You choose scale factor to be what you want and obviously limit the rating as maximum 10. This way, you reward mutiple image uploads, but you reward users with higher quality image uploads too. Consider someone automates uploading images with some type of web bot and all images are considered poor by users - do you want to reward it? This way you can reward multiple uploads, but better quality uploads are treated more favourably. Maybe not what you are looking for but worth considering perhaps - only you can decide....

Comment: +1 i like that approach, but i have to add as the user rating for one picture is at least one - your solution does also go out of bounds for huge number of uploads, you can fix this by `subtracting 1` from the average or use the `ImageUploadCount` as an exponent of `(AverageRating/10)^(2*ImageUploadCount)`.

Comment: @epsilon'εⳆ2'halbe Yes I did say you have to limit it at 10. The formula was not meant to be exact, I was just trying to illustrate a possible alternative strategy for your ratings concept

Comment: sorry I misunderstood that then.

Comment: @epsilon'εⳆ2'halbe The point is that you can play with the numbers to get what you want, the idea was just that maybe its not good to reward poor quality images and reward better quality more than poor.

Comment: and an open scale solves the problem of any out of bounds error, which is not unlikely to be happening. I wish I could give another +1 for that.